# Get Binary Data out of HBase

Tags: hbase, cloudera, binary-data

I am experiencing with HBase (Cloudera 5.7 Distribution) and have a question.
I store Binary Data (PDF's, Word, JPEG, ...) in HBase with the new MOB function activated ([MOB Documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_mob.html), [Description of MOB-Concept](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/06/inside-apache-hbases-new-support-for-mobs/) )

To store the data is not the problem. But, how can I get the files out of HBase (preferebly with save as dialogue)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Cloudera documentation on MOB support

> The feature is transparent to the client.

(https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/admin_hbase_mob.html)

This means that you can get the content of the stored MOB the same way as from any other column.
In Java:

```
        String namespace = "nmsp";
        String tblName = "MOB_TEST";
        byte[] rowKey = "MOB_1".getBytes();
        byte[] columnFamily = "D".getBytes();
        byte[] qualifier = "MOB".getBytes();

        Get g = new Get(rowKey);
        g.addColumn(columnFamily, qualifier);

        Configuration cfg = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(cfg);
        Table t = con.getTable(TableName.valueOf(namespace, tblName));

        Result r = t.get(g);
        byte[] mobContent = r.getValue(columnFamily, qualifier);

        Path outPath = FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getPath("C:/testBigFile_fromHBase.xml");
        Files.write(outPath, mobContent);
```